# RxJava test Observable

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, rx-java, reactive-programming

There is something like [`TestSubscriber`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html). It has very useful functions like [`awaitTerminalEvent()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html#awaitTerminalEvent()), [`getOnNextEvents()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html#getOnNextEvents()), etc.

Is there an equivalent of `TestSubscriber` for `Observable` that might be pinned to some observable in the middle of sequence?

I would like to test some specific cases, one of which is:

- I have a class that accepts `Observable` in constructor. One of it's methods invokes that `Observable` inside `onErrorResumeNext` operator. So executing the main `Observable` under specific conditions might invoke tested `Observable`. Something like `assertExecuted` is needed.
- In the case described above I would like to test `Thread` the `Observable` is executed on.
- I would like to know, what `Observable` returned based on it's input.

Each of those cases require workarounds like:

```
observable
  .doOnNext(o -> {
      // Observable was given a value
   });
```

If there is no nice way already available, how to make the call above cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions need to be tested outside of the lambdas that are part of the observable because the lambdas themselves may never run (like in your `onErrorResumeNext` case). So you need some object defined outside of the observable to carry the result that we want to test.

A common technique for testing observables is to use Atomic objects to record events:

```
AtomicBoolean executed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
Observable
  .empty()
  .doOnNext(t -> executed.set(true))
  .subscribe();
assertFalse(executed.get());
```

This example could be better done with `TestSubscriber` but it shows the technique.

[rxjava-extras](http://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras) has convenience classes if you are using java 6 (heck just use retrolambda) so that you don't need to write anonymous classes for this use case:

```
AtomicBoolean executed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
Observable
  .empty()
  .doOnNext(Actions.setToTrue(executed))
  .subscribe();
assertFalse(executed.get());
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `Atomic` objects from `java.util.concurrent` package. So as I undestood, tested observable must be `wrapped` and have operators added, if I need to test, if it properly executes. Thank you for your response.